# Application logging for Windows IoT UWP application

Tags: logging, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I have UWP project running on Windows IoT Core 10.
I can not debug it remotely, so I made my own file logging.
However some time application exits without any error, I guess it some unhandled exceptions.
Where can I find the log and how can I read it?

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to set up crash dump generation for postmortem analysis. Also note that UWP applications can be killed by system anytime.

Comment: "Also note that UWP applications can be killed by system anytime" - OK... What the solution? We have RT embedded system that must be live.
And how to configure dumping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the live process dump file for debugging hanging processes which are in user mode.
[image]

You can also use [Event Tracing for Windows(ETW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/eventtracing) to trace the event logs. ETW enables the consistent, straightforward capture of kernel and application events.